# No module named 'projecta' when running in docker but works in PyCharm

Tags: python, docker, flask

I have a Python Flask application setup in PyCharm. The folder structure for the project is as follows:

```
- README.md
- .gitignore
- projecta/
      - __init__.py
      - src/__init__.py
      - src/app.py
      - src/api/hello.py
      - src/service/helloService.py
      - Dockerfile
      - requirements.txt 
- projectb/
```

In my dockerfile, I have the following content:

```
FROM python:3.6
RUN mkdir /projecta
WORKDIR /projecta
ADD . /projecta/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["python", "/projecta/src/app.py"]
```

In my PyCharm, I run it as a Python Configuration with script path as `path-to-folder/projecta/src/app.py` and working directory as `path-to-folder/projecta/src`.

When I run from PyCharm, things run normally without any issues. But when I run from docker using `docker run -d --name a a:0.0.2` and building using `docker build -t a:0.0.2 .`, it gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/projecta/src/app.py", line 3, in <module>

from projecta.src.api import api

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'projecta'
```

I am not expert in Python/Flask nor Docker. Can someone point out what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `from .api import api` in line 3 of app.py

It will not run in pycharm then but will go well in docker

Comment: now I am getting `File "/projecta/src/app.py", line 3, in <module>

from .api import apiModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.api'; '__main__' is not a package`